# Vue-Router, router.onReady()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to vue. I would like to understand when exactly onReady() function will be fired. Vue Router docs explains this below

> This method queues a callback to be called when the router has completed the initial navigation, which means it has resolved all async enter hooks and async components that are associated with the initial route.

However, I am not quite understand couple of things here,

1. What does initial navigation mean?
2. What does it mean by async enter hooks?

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Just in my opition, not very clear of it, hope there will be more authoritative answer.

1.When vue-router instance initialization finished.(Like when page refreshed, vue-router need create new instance.)

2.async hooks means routes that specific a async component.(When pack with webpack , it will split code into a chunk.)

  `{
    path: '/payment',
    component: () => import('@/view/payment'),
  },`

Comment: I think that's close enough, but to add more understanding for `2.`:

Async enter hooks are the ones that are named `beforeEnter` (router-level) or `beforeRouteEnter` (component-level). Docs about them [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

Async components is like what cxxsn said.

Mind that it is now called `isReady` instead of `onReady` in vue3 vue-router.